# How to add additional help_text to a model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a standard model:

```
class Book(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=None,
        verbose_name='These are books',
        help_text='Provide a title for your book'
    )
```

Is there any way I can add a second `help_text2` or `placeholder_text` so I can render an input placeholder as well as help text when displaying a `model.Form`? I want to do this inside the model, not inside the form (which I know I can do with Widgets).

For example:

```
class Book(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=None,
        verbose_name='These are books',
        help_text='Provide a title for your book',
        placeholder='E.g. My First Book'
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve that is to inherit from the built-in `CharField` (as an example) and add the `placeholder` attribute to it:

```
from django.db import models

class CharFieldWithPlaceholder(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.placeholder = kwargs.pop('placeholder')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```